# Changing way of calculating score in results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my index created like this:

```
'body' => [
    'settings' => [
        'analysis' => [
            'filter' => [
                'ngram_filter' => [
                    'type' => 'ngram',
                    'min_gram' => 2,
                    'max_gram' => 20,
                ],
            ],
            'analyzer' => [
                'ngram_analyzer' => [
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'filter' => [
                        'lowercase',
                        'ngram_filter',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'mappings' => [
        'doc' => [
            '_all' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'analyzer' => 'ngram_analyzer',
                'search_analyzer' => 'standard',
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'pagetitle' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'include_in_all' => true,
                    'term_vector' => 'yes',
                    'analyzer' => 'ngram_analyzer',
                    'search_analyzer' => 'standard',
                ],
                'searchable_content' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'include_in_all' => true,
                    'term_vector' => 'yes',
                    'analyzer' => 'ngram_analyzer',
                    'search_analyzer' => 'standard',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

and I look for results like this:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Loesungen",
                    "fields": ["pagetitle^2", "searchable_content"],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "term": {
                            "category.weight": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 3,
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "pagetitle": {},
            "searchable_content": {}
        }
    },    
}
```

Desired effect:

- documents with work in pagetitle are more important that documents with word in searchable_content
- documents that have word in both pagetitle and in searchable_content is more important that document that have this word only in pagetitle

However when I search, I'm getting results like this:

```
{
    "highlight": {
        "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
        ]
    },
    "_score": 470.29608,
}, {
    "highlight": {
        "searchable_content": [
            "text <em>Lösungen</em> text"
        ],
        "pagetitle": [
            "<em>Lösungen</em>"
        ]
    },
    "_score": 441.84506
}
```

so as you see document with word only in title has higher score that document with this word in both title and content.

The question is - what should be changed to make it work as I described? Creating index or something in query?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `most_fields` on your multi_match query.
The default is `best_fields.
This section of the documentation seems promising in your case:

> ...By combining scores from all three fields we can match as many
>   documents as possible with the main field, but use the second and
>   third fields to push the most similar results to the top of the list.

Also, there's the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html,) which is useful (thought a bit complex) for debugging relevancy.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

```
Query : GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "Loesungen",
                    "fields": ["pagetitle^2", "searchable_content"],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                    "type":       "most_fields"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "term": {
                            "category.weight": 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 3,
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "pagetitle": {},
            "searchable_content": {}
        }
    },    
}
```

Comment: I verified what you wrote and the results order is the same but the result with score  441.84506 got higher result 459.42462. The strange thing is when I wrote the exact word (`Lösungen` instead of `Loesungen`) the order of results is as expected